# Attaching private route table to NAT Gateway using for each terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, nat

In Terraform, I have a NAT gateway for every public subnet created. I am trying to create a route table for my private subnet to point to the NAT gateway. In my terraform code I created my nat gateways using for_each specifying for every public subnet I have, there needs to be a NAT gateway. I am getting an issue when referring to each instance of my NAT Gateway. Any advice would be helpful. Below is my code and error:

```
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "main" {
  for_each      = aws_subnet.public
  subnet_id     = each.value.id
  allocation_id = aws_eip.main[each.key].id
}

resource "aws_route_table" "nat" {
  for_each = var.priv_subnet
  vpc_id   = aws_vpc.main.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.main[each.key].id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = var.rt_tags_private
  }
}
```

**Error**

```
Error: Invalid index

  on vpc.tf line 71, in resource "aws_route_table" "nat":
  71:     gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.main[each.key].id
    |----------------
    | aws_nat_gateway.main is object with 1 attribute "MainPubSub1"
    | each.key is "0"

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

Comment: Your NAT Gateways are associated with public subnets, but you're trying to reference them by iterating private subnets. You need to figure out which public subnet corresponds to which private subnet, based on availability zone. I don't think that you'll be able to do this in an automated fashion (although I haven't looked at the data providers in 0.13).

Comment: Got it working! Thanks!

Comment: It might be useful to others if you answered your own question and showed what you did.

Answer (score 0):

I tought of posting what I believe may fix this in case others have a similar issue.

This could be solved by [chaining for_each between resources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html#chaining-for_each-between-resources)

```
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "main" {
  for_each      = aws_subnet.public
  subnet_id     = each.value.id
  allocation_id = aws_eip.main[each.key].id
}

resource "aws_route_table" "nat" {
  for_each = aws_nat_gateway.main
  vpc_id   = aws_vpc.main.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = each.value.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = var.rt_tags_private
  }
}
```

In the expression `aws_eip.main[each.key].id`, the `each.key` part takes the key for `aws_subnet.public["key"]`.

I noticed the solution to the problem was said to be found, however, I tought of sharing.